# CPU usage reporting in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, report

I am trying to get the CPU usage of a mac over time.

I am using this top cmd in terminal getting the result i want but would like it to output to a file and update every 5 seconds.

top -l 1 | grep -E "^CPU|^Phys"

CPU usage: 3.27% user, 14.75% sys, 81.96% idle 
PhysMem: 5807M used (1458M wired), 10G unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command prints all 3 CPU usage percentages **tab-separated** to a file (appending line by line for each call):

```
top -l1 | grep -E "CPU usage:" |  awk -v FS="CPU usage: | user, | sys, | idle" '{print $2, $3, $4}' >> cpu_user_sys_idle.tsv
```

Works with pipe separated command chain:

1. **Top** as you suggested
2. **Grep** to filter only line with CPU usage
3. **Awk** with variable *field-separator* (-v **FS**) using either of the 4 strings to get all percentages as isolated fields. Then print second, third and fourth (omit first since it is empty).
4. **>>** redirects output appending to file (e.g. *cpu_user_sys_idle.tsv*)

You additionally can put it into automated or scheduled (apple)script to collect measures in regular intervals.

Comment: Thank you for the replay! I also found a way, this is more of a manual way. 

[while true; do top -l 1 | grep -E ^CPU >> CPU_Usage.csv; sleep 15; done]